# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am getting this error even though I have a named entityManager in the configuration.

This is a spring-boot application and I am running the code that way.

As you can see below, my configuration has a name entityManager called "mysqlEntityManager.

What I am doing wrong?  Why does it keep trying to use "entityManager" instead of my "mysqlEntityManager"?

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field bookDao in com.example.demo.service.impl.BookServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.example.demo.configuration;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.example.demo.entity.User;


/**
 * Spring configuration of the "mysql" database.
 * 
 * @author Radouane ROUFID.
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager", 
        basePackages = "com.example.demo.dao"
)
public class MysqlConfiguration {

    /**
     * MySQL datasource definition.
     * 
     * @return datasource.
     */
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .build();
    }

    /**
     * Entity manager definition. 
     *  
     * @param builder an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
     * @return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
     */
    @Bean(name = "mysqlEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                    .dataSource(mysqlDataSource())
                    .properties(hibernateProperties())
                    .packages("com.example.demo.enity")
                    .persistenceUnit("mysqlPU")
                    .build();
    }

    /**
     * @param entityManagerFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "mysqlTransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager(@Qualifier("mysqlEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");
        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                                        e -> e.getKey().toString(),
                                                        e -> e.getValue())
                                                    );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }
}

    /**
 * 
 */
package com.example.demo.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import com.example.demo.entity.Book;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */

public interface BookDao extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.authorName = ?1")
    public List<Book> getByAuthor( String author );

    @Query("SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.title = ?1")
    public List<Book> getByTitle( String title );
}
```

Service implementation:

```
    /**
 * 
 */
package com.example.demo.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.demo.dao.BookDao;
import com.example.demo.entity.Book;
import com.example.demo.service.BookService;

/**
 * @author denisputnam
 *
 */
@Service("bookService")
@Transactional(value="mysqlTransactionManager")
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger (this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#getByAuthorName(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public List<Book> getByAuthorName(String name) {
        return this.bookDao.getByAuthor(name);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#getByTitle(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public List<Book> getByTitle(String title) {
        return this.bookDao.getByTitle(title);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#create(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Book create(String title, String author) throws Exception {
        Book book = null;
        try {
            book = new Book();
            book.setAuthorName(author);
            book.setTitle(title);
            this.bookDao.saveAndFlush(book);
        }catch( Exception e ) {
            log.error("Error creating book: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e);
        }

        return book;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#updateBook(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public Book updateBook(Long id, String title, String author) throws Exception {
        Book book = null;
        try{
            book = bookDao.findOne(id);
            book.setAuthorName(author);
            book.setTitle(title);
            bookDao.saveAndFlush(book);
        }catch( Exception e ){
            log.error("Error updating the book: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return book;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#delete(java.lang.Long)
     */
    @Override
    public Book delete(Long id) throws Exception {
        Book book = null;
        try {
            book = bookDao.findOne(id);
            bookDao.delete(book);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error deleting the book: " + e.getMessage());
            throw new Exception(e);
        }
        return book;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#findAll()
     */
    @Override
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return this.bookDao.findAll();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see com.example.demo.service.BookService#findOne(java.lang.Long)
     */
    @Override
    public Book findOne(Long id) {
        return this.bookDao.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

pom.xml - dependencies:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-configuration-processor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
         </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties:

```
    #server.port=8090  do this in vm args as -Dserver.port=8090

spring.oracle.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1532/DEMODB

spring.oracle.datasource.username=denismp
spring.oracle.datasource.password=password
spring.oracle.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbs.driver.OracleDriver
#spring.oracle.datasource.jndi-name=java/comp/env/jdbd/demodb
#spring.oracle.jpa.properties.hibernate.hdm2dll=autoupdate
#spring.oracle.jpa.hibernate-connection.release_mode=on_close

spring.application.name=demo
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframwork.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext

spring.basic.enable=false


# ------------------------------
# MYSQL DATABASE CONFIGURATION
# ------------------------------
spring.mysql.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.mysql.datasource.username=cars
spring.mysql.datasource.password=cars
spring.mysql.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# -----------------------
# POSTGRESQL DATABASE CONFIGURATION
# -----------------------
spring.postgresql.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/book_db
spring.postgresql.datasource.username=postgres
spring.postgresql.datasource.password=postgres
spring.postgresql.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

hibernate.properties:

```
    # Spring DATA JPA Configuration
hiberate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2dll.auto=update
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle11gDialect
#hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.createorupdate=update
hibernate.connection.release_mode=on_close
hibernate.id.new_genrator_mappings=true
```

Updated Application.java. I added the @EnableAutoConfiguration.  Don't know if this is required.:

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo")
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.example.demo.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.dao")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application ) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass );
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;
}
```

Added these two lines to the application.properties file.  This was required to get the tables to generate.  This is different from previous version of the STS IDE:

```
    spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
sprint.jpa.hibernate-ddl-auto=create
```

I modified the MysqlConfiguration.java file to replace anything that has "mysqlTransactionManager and mysqlEntityManager to transactionManager and entityManager.  This one concerns me if I want to connect to more than one db:

```
    package com.example.demo.configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

//import com.example.entity.User;

/**
 * Spring configuration of the "mysql" database.
 * 
 * @author Radouane ROUFID.
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
// @EnableJpaRepositories(
// entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager",
// transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager",
// basePackages = "com.example.demo.dao"
// )
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", 
        basePackages = {
        "com.example.demo.dao" })
public class MysqlConfiguration {

    /**
     * MySQL datasource definition.
     * 
     * @return datasource.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mysql.datasource")
    public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /**
     * Entity manager definition.
     * 
     * @param builder
     *            an EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.
     * @return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(mysqlDataSource()).properties(hibernateProperties())
                .packages("com.example.demo.entity").persistenceUnit("mysqlPU").build();
    }

    /**
     * @param entityManagerFactory
     * @return
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {

        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties");
        try {
            Properties properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            return properties.entrySet().stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new HashMap<String, Object>();
        }
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }

//  @Bean
//  JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
//      JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
//      transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
//      return transactionManager;
//  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot auto-configuration anywhere? Can you provide the dependencies you are using?

Comment: Hi Sean, I added the dependencies for your review.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the changes I made to the configuration annotations and the application.properties file.  I also changed anything in the service that referenced "mysqlTransactionManager" to "transactionManager".  Perhaps someone can explain how one would connect to more than on database if "transactionManager" and "enitityManager" are required to get things to work.

For now I am going to post this as an answer.  Please correct anything that I have done wrong.

P.S.  (Somewhat of a rant here) I find it interesting that someone down voted me because I did not do enough research on the problem.  This is a very big assumption and certainly did not help me solve my problem, which is what I thought this website is for.

FYI, I worked this problem for 3 days, with a full day of research before I posted my question.  If the solution is so obvious, then perhaps the person who down voted me could have just posted the answer and saved me a couple of days of struggling with this issue.

At any rate, I hope this is some help for someone.  I put the project up on https://github.com/denismp/demo if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably missed @Repository Annotation in BookDao. If it is ok then check for database name in application properties which should be match with database name you have created your mysql/oracle database.

Comment: I don't think it is getting as far connecting to the database.  It is failing on the  configuration.